# Managing secret and non-secret variables in Github Actions

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, github-actions

Currently my Github Action integration workflow file (called it `workflow.yml`) looks like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    steps:
    - name: create env file
      run: |
        touch .env

        echo API_KEY=${{ secrets.API_KEY }} >> .env
        echo DB_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }} >> .env

        echo ENVIRONMENT=staging >> .env
        echo API_PORT=8080 >> .env
        echo S3_BUCKET=my-bucket >> .env

        # ... many more lines like this
```

Is there any other better approach than this one? I've thought of having a pre-made `environments/staging.env` containing all the non-secrets variables, that I would then complete with the secret ones, but then it feels awkward because we'd be declaring non-secret variable in one place (the `staging.env` file) and secret variables in another place (this Yaml file).

Would it be possible to have one single file with a syntax approaching this:

```sh
# staging.env
API_KEY=${{ secrets.API_KEY }}
DB_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}
ENVIRONMENT=staging
API_PORT=8080
S3_BUCKET=my-bucket
```

and then, from the Yaml workflow, we would load this file and the `%{{ secrets.foobar }}` would be interpreted?

Comment: Why not avoid using .env file, and just use the `env` key in the workflow to set all environment variables? It is clear, readable and centralized.

Comment: @DannyB we're using docker-compose with a `env_file: .env` directive and downstream it's more convenient to do this — it's only problematic for the github workflow

Comment: You could use a different workflow.yml file for each environment, each one with its own configuration. Similar to what you did, using environment variables (as explained here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow) with repo secrets.